# How to secure OneNote cache ( having sensitive information)

Tags: security, encryption, sync, cache, onedrive

I am using Boxcryptor to encrypt the entire OneDrive folder by saving OneNote 2016 files to my PC in an Encrypted OneDrive Folder, which automatically gets synchronized with OneDrive. To make this work I had to block OneNote internet.

But how should I secure cached OneNote data on my local hard drive?

*What I checked already:*

1. I tested making cache location on Encrypted OneDrive Folder but OneNote is crashing.
2. I can't use OneDrive built-in encryption using passwords because:

   a. It doesn't support whole notebook protection with one password. I will have to protect each notebook section one by one & also unlocking one by one with the password when seeing & also when searching the whole notebook.

   b. There is no way to recover the password if I forget.

Or there are any other ways to encrypt(client side) Notes & sync with the cloud ?

Comment: "But how should I secure cached OneNote data on my local hard drive?" - Use FDE (Full Disk Encryption) or EFS (Encrypted File System).  However, if you are worried about forgetting your password you have larger issues at play and honestly, no method will secure your data but provide you means to recover if you "forget the password'

Answer (score 1):

I have a very unorthodox solution that might work.

1. Save the Cache inside of a volume [veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html)  and sync it as you wish, however it doesn't seem to support incremental uploads, so you have to re-sync the whole container every time you change something.
2. Save your password in a password manager, I recommend something like [Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/), it's easy to recover access to the service, there is a ton of recovery choices and safe enough if you use two-step authentication, and of course, you can make offline backups as you wish.

Well, the user above already answered something similar.